# Cauchy definition of limits

Tags: limits, definition

$a\in\Bbb R,g\in\Bbb R$
a) $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= g$
b) $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= \infty$
c) $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= -\infty$

a)  ∀ε>0 ∃M>0 ∀x∈R ( x>M => |f(x) - g| < ε
b)  ∀ε>0 ∃M>0 ∀x∈R ( x > M => f(x) > ε
c)  ∀ε>0 ∃M>0 ∀x∈R ( x > M => f(x) > -ε

Are those definitions correct?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit your question to include the text, not links to an image, if you show what you have tried and where you are stuck, and if you ask just one question per post. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: of course function f(x)

Comment: a) and b) look good. Think again about c). It must at least contain $a$ and $f(x)\color{red}<-\epsilon$.

Comment: so, ∀ε>0 ∃M>0 ∀x∈R  |x - a | < M => f(x) < -ε ?

Comment: @NoName Looks good to me.